# Searches through the whole div

Tags: javascript, html

I have this script:

```
    function search_animal() {
        let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value
        input = input.toLowerCase();
        let x = document.getElementsByClassName('separateline');

        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
                x[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            else {
                x[i].style.display = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I have this multiple divs with this class

```
                <div class="separateline">
                    <a class="tabcontentlink" href="shablon.html">Dog</a>
                    <p class="line"></p>
                </div>
```

However when I use a search bar it searches through the whole div, when I need it to search only through the visible text "Dog".
For example if I enter "tabcontentlink" in the search bar it will find all the divs, because all of them are named like this and the biggest problem is if I enter parts of the word "tabcontentlink" it will still find it.

Comment: so use textContent instead of innerHTML

Comment: Thank you very much this has fixed my issue.

Comment: Feel free to delete the question

Comment: I've got another question. Maybe someone can help. Is there a way to highlight the matching text which matches?